# installation of customizeable ubuntu 22.04 is failed at apt step

Tags: system-installation

Install of ubuntu 22.04 live server is failed at apt step during install

[image]

root@ubuntu-server:/target/var/log/installer# cat -n curtin-install.log

```
     1  curtin: Installation started. (21.3-12-ga74424850)
     2  start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: curtin command block-meta

 
   353  devsync happy - path /dev/vda now exists
   354  return volume path /dev/vda
   355  Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   356  get_blockdev_sector_size: info:
   357  {
   358   "vda": {
   359    "ALIGNMENT": "0",
   360    "DISC-ALN": "0",
   361    "DISC-GRAN": "0",
   362    "DISC-MAX": "0",
   363    "DISC-ZERO": "0",
   364    "FSTYPE": "",
   365    "GROUP": "disk",
   366    "KNAME": "vda",
   367    "LABEL": "",
   368    "LOG-SEC": "512",
   369    "MAJ:MIN": "252:0",
   370    "MIN-IO": "512",
   371    "MODE": "brw-rw----",
   372    "MODEL": "",
   373    "MOUNTPOINT": "",
   374    "NAME": "vda",
   375    "OPT-IO": "0",
   376    "OWNER": "root",
   377    "PHY-SEC": "512",
   378    "RM": "0",
   379    "RO": "0",
   380    "ROTA": "1",
   381    "RQ-SIZE": "256",
   382    "SIZE": "32212252672",
   383    "STATE": "",
   384    "TYPE": "disk",
   385    "UUID": "",
   386    "device_path": "/dev/vda"
   387   },
   388   "vda1": {
   389    "ALIGNMENT": "0",
   390    "DISC-ALN": "0",
   391    "DISC-GRAN": "0",
   392    "DISC-MAX": "0",
   393    "DISC-ZERO": "0",
   394    "FSTYPE": "",
   395    "GROUP": "disk",
   396    "KNAME": "vda1",
   397    "LABEL": "",
   398    "LOG-SEC": "512",
   399    "MAJ:MIN": "252:1",
   400    "MIN-IO": "512",
   401    "MODE": "brw-rw----",
   402    "MODEL": "",
   403    "MOUNTPOINT": "",
   404    "NAME": "vda1",
   405    "OPT-IO": "0",
   406    "OWNER": "root",
   407    "PHY-SEC": "512",
   408    "RM": "0",
   409    "RO": "0",
   410    "ROTA": "1",
   411    "RQ-SIZE": "256",
   412    "SIZE": "1048576",
   413    "STATE": "",
   414    "TYPE": "part",
   415    "UUID": "",
   416    "device_path": "/dev/vda1"
   417   },
   418   "vda2": {
   419    "ALIGNMENT": "0",
   420    "DISC-ALN": "0",
   421    "DISC-GRAN": "0",
   422    "DISC-MAX": "0",
   423    "DISC-ZERO": "0",
   424    "FSTYPE": "ext4",
   425    "GROUP": "disk",
   426    "KNAME": "vda2",
   427    "LABEL": "",
   428    "LOG-SEC": "512",
   429    "MAJ:MIN": "252:2",
   430    "MIN-IO": "512",
   431    "MODE": "brw-rw----",
   432    "MODEL": "",
   433    "MOUNTPOINT": "",
   434    "NAME": "vda2",
   435    "OPT-IO": "0",
   436    "OWNER": "root",
   437    "PHY-SEC": "512",
   438    "RM": "0",
   439    "RO": "0",
   440    "ROTA": "1",
   441    "RQ-SIZE": "256",
   442    "SIZE": "2147483648",
   443    "STATE": "",
   444    "TYPE": "part",
   445    "UUID": "d1fe52ff-5282-4c49-a1de-3e9d5f630846",
   446    "device_path": "/dev/vda2"
   447   }
   448  }
   449  get_blockdev_sector_size: (log=512, phys=512)
   450  vda logical_block_size_bytes: 512
   451  previous partition number for 'partition-2' found to be '2'
   452  partition_kname=vda2
   453  calc_partition_info: vda2 size_sectors=4194304 start_sectors=4096
   454  adding partition 'partition-2' to disk 'disk-vda' (ptable: 'gpt')
   455  partnum: 3 offset_sectors: 4198400 length_sectors: 58712063
   456  Preparing partition location on disk /dev/vda
   457  Wiping 1M on /dev/vda at offset 2149580800
   458  Running command ['sgdisk', '--new', '3:4198400:62910463', '--typecode=3:8300', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   459  Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   460  /dev/vda is multipath device? False
   461  Running command ['blockdev', '--rereadpt', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   462  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   463  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.299
   464  TIMED udevadm_settle(exists='/dev/vda3'): 0.000
   465  finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: configuring partition: partition-2
   466  start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: configuring lvm_volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
   467  get_path_to_storage_volume for volume partition-2({'device': 'disk-vda', 'size': 30060576768, 'wipe': 'superblock', 'flag': '', 'number': 3, 'preserve': False, 'grub_device': False, 'type': 'partition', 'id': 'partition-2'})
   468  get_path_to_storage_volume for volume disk-vda({'ptable': 'gpt', 'path': '/dev/vda', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'name': '', 'grub_device': True, 'type': 'disk', 'id': 'disk-vda'})
   469  Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   470  /dev/vda is multipath device member? False
   471  Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
   472  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   473  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.187
   474  devsync happy - path /dev/vda now exists
   475  return volume path /dev/vda
   476  Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
   477  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   478  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.183
   479  devsync happy - path /dev/vda now exists
   480  return volume path /dev/vda3
   481  Running command ['vgcreate', '--force', '--zero=y', '--yes', 'ubuntu-vg', '/dev/vda3'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   482  Running command ['pvscan'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   483  Running command ['vgscan'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   484  finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: configuring lvm_volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
   485  start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: configuring lvm_partition: lvm_partition-0
   486  Running command ['lvcreate', 'ubuntu-vg', '--name', 'ubuntu-lv', '--zero=y', '--wipesignatures=y', '--yes', '--size', '15028191232.0B'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   487    Logical volume "ubuntu-lv" created.
   488  Running command ['pvscan'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   489  Running command ['vgscan'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   490  get_path_to_storage_volume for volume lvm_partition-0({'name': 'ubuntu-lv', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '15028191232B', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'lvm_partition', 'id': 'lvm_partition-0'})
   491  Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
   492  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   493  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.099
   494  devsync happy - path /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv now exists
   495  return volume path /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
   496  Wiping logical volume /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv mode=superblock
   497  wiping 1M on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv at offsets [0, -1048576]
   498  get_path_to_storage_volume for volume lvm_partition-0({'name': 'ubuntu-lv', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '15028191232B', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'lvm_partition', 'id': 'lvm_partition-0'})
   499  Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
   500  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   501  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.148
   502  devsync happy - path /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv now exists
   503  return volume path /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
   504  Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   505  Creating dname udev rule '['SUBSYSTEM=="block"', 'ACTION=="add|change"', 'ENV{DM_NAME}=="ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv"', 'SYMLINK+="disk/by-dname/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv"\n']'
   506  finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: configuring lvm_partition: lvm_partition-0
   507  start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: configuring format: format-1
   508  get_path_to_storage_volume for volume lvm_partition-0({'name': 'ubuntu-lv', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '15028191232B', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'lvm_partition', 'id': 'lvm_partition-0'})
   509  Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
   510  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   511  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.147
   512  devsync happy - path /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv now exists
   513  return volume path /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
   514  mkfs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv info: {'fstype': 'ext4', 'volume': 'lvm_partition-0', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'format', 'id': 'format-1'}
   515  Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   516  get_blockdev_sector_size: info:
   517  {
   518   "dm-0": {
   519    "ALIGNMENT": "0",
   520    "DISC-ALN": "0",
   521    "DISC-GRAN": "0",
   522    "DISC-MAX": "0",
   523    "DISC-ZERO": "0",
   524    "FSTYPE": "",
   525    "GROUP": "disk",
   526    "KNAME": "dm-0",
   527    "LABEL": "",
   528    "LOG-SEC": "512",
   529    "MAJ:MIN": "253:0",
   530    "MIN-IO": "512",
   531    "MODE": "brw-rw----",
   532    "MODEL": "",
   533    "MOUNTPOINT": "",
   534    "NAME": "ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv",
   535    "OPT-IO": "0",
   536    "OWNER": "root",
   537    "PHY-SEC": "512",
   538    "RM": "0",
   539    "RO": "0",
   540    "ROTA": "1",
   541    "RQ-SIZE": "128",
   542    "SIZE": "15028191232",
   543    "STATE": "running",
   544    "TYPE": "lvm",
   545    "UUID": "",
   546    "device_path": "/dev/dm-0"
   547   }
   548  }
   549  get_blockdev_sector_size: (log=512, phys=512)
   550  Running command ['mkfs.ext4', '-F', '-U', '9bad6ac5-1b6d-4fd7-8d53-ac1fafc3f2bc', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   551  Formated device type: lvm_partition
   552  finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: configuring format: format-1
   553  start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: configuring mount: mount-1
   554  get_path_to_storage_volume for volume lvm_partition-0({'name': 'ubuntu-lv', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '15028191232B', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'lvm_partition', 'id': 'lvm_partition-0'})
   555  Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
   556  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   557  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.154
   558  devsync happy - path /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv now exists
   559  return volume path /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
   560  volume_path=/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv found slaves: ['vda3']
   561  kname_is_iscsi: no iscsi disk found for kname dm-0
   562  kname_is_iscsi: no iscsi disk found for kname vda3
   563  Running command ['mount', '-t', 'ext4', '-o', 'defaults', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv', '/target/'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   564  Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   565  Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   566  volspec: path=/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv type=lvm
   567  info[DEVLINKS] = ['/dev/disk/by-uuid/9bad6ac5-1b6d-4fd7-8d53-ac1fafc3f2bc', '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv', '/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv', '/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-qRlJElzwOfxhnAZJyKhK16tgwuMdyLQ5772dMQeMouqsgwLs7xXpcKuzXrgo3Dlg', '/dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv']
   568  finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: configuring mount: mount-1
   569  start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: configuring mount: mount-0
   570  get_path_to_storage_volume for volume partition-1({'device': 'disk-vda', 'size': 2147483648, 'wipe': 'superblock', 'flag': '', 'number': 2, 'preserve': False, 'grub_device': False, 'type': 'partition', 'id': 'partition-1'})
   571  get_path_to_storage_volume for volume disk-vda({'ptable': 'gpt', 'path': '/dev/vda', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'name': '', 'grub_device': True, 'type': 'disk', 'id': 'disk-vda'})
   572  Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   573  /dev/vda is multipath device member? False
   574  Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
   575  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   576  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.411
   577  devsync happy - path /dev/vda now exists
   578  return volume path /dev/vda
   579  Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/vda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
   580  Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   581  TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.091
   582  devsync happy - path /dev/vda now exists
   583  return volume path /dev/vda2
   584  volume_path=/dev/vda2 found slaves: ['vda2']
   585  kname_is_iscsi: no iscsi disk found for kname vda2
   586  kname_is_iscsi: no iscsi disk found for kname vda2
   587  Running command ['mount', '-t', 'ext4', '-o', 'defaults', '/dev/vda2', '/target/boot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   588  Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/vda2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   589  Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/vda2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   590  volspec: path=/dev/vda2 type=part
   591  info[DEVLINKS] = ['/dev/disk/by-path/virtio-pci-0000:00:04.0-part2', '/dev/disk/by-partuuid/e2644319-da8d-4613-9efb-a59f5bb135b1', '/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:04.0-part2', '/dev/disk/by-uuid/d1fe52ff-5282-4c49-a1de-3e9d5f630846']
   592  finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: configuring mount: mount-0
   593  TIMED BLOCK_META: 12.450
   594  finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: curtin command block-meta
   595  start: cmd-install/stage-extract/builtin/cmd-extract: curtin command extract
   596  Installing sources: [{'type': 'tgz', 'uri': 'cp:///tmp/tmphv0ahhgj/mount'}] to target at /target
   597  start: cmd-install/stage-extract/builtin/cmd-extract: acquiring and extracting image from cp:///tmp/tmphv0ahhgj/mount
   598  Running command ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p "$2" && cd "$2" && rsync -aXHAS --one-file-system "$1/" .', '--', '/tmp/tmphv0ahhgj/mount', '/target'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
   599  finish: cmd-install/stage-extract/builtin/cmd-extract: SUCCESS: acquiring and extracting image from cp:///tmp/tmphv0ahhgj/mount
   600  Applying write_files from config.
   601  finish: cmd-install/stage-extract/builtin/cmd-extract: SUCCESS: curtin command extract
   602  start: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: curtin command curthooks
   603  Running curtin builtin curthooks
   604  Configuring target system for distro: ubuntu osfamily: debian
   605  start: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/writing-apt-config: configuring apt configuring apt
   606  Transferred {'subiquity': ''} into new format: {'debconf_selections': {'subiquity': ''}}
   607  curthooks handling apt to target /target with config {'debconf_selections': {'subiquity': ''}}
   608  Running command ['unshare', '--help'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   609  Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'lsb_release', '--all'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   610  Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'dpkg', '--print-architecture'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   611  got primary mirror: None
   612  got security mirror: None
   613  Apt Mirror info: {'PRIMARY': 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/', 'SECURITY': 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/', 'MIRROR': 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/'}
   614  Applying debconf selections
   615  Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'debconf-set-selections'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   616  Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'dpkg-query', '--list'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   617  finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/writing-apt-config: FAIL: configuring apt configuring apt
   618  finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: FAIL: curtin command curthooks
   619  Traceback (most recent call last):
   620    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
   621      ret = args.func(args)
   622    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 1886, in curthooks
   623      builtin_curthooks(cfg, target, state)
   624    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 1692, in builtin_curthooks
   625      do_apt_config(cfg, target)
   626    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 97, in do_apt_config
   627      apt_config.handle_apt(apt_cfg, target)
   628    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/apt_config.py", line 73, in handle_apt
   629      apply_debconf_selections(cfg, target)
   630    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/apt_config.py", line 162, in apply_debconf_selections
   631      pkgs_installed = distro.get_installed_packages(target)
   632    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 453, in get_installed_packages
   633      (out, _) = subp(['dpkg-query', '--list'], target=target, capture=True)
   634    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 275, in subp
   635      return _subp(*args, **kwargs)
   636    File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 139, in _subp
   637      raise ProcessExecutionError(stdout=out, stderr=err,
   638  curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
   639  Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'dpkg-query', '--list']
   640  Exit code: 2
   641  Reason: -
   642  Stdout: ''
   643  Stderr: dpkg-query: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1913 package 'file':
   644           multiple non-coinstallable package instances present; most probably due to an upgrade from an unofficial dpkg
   645
   646  Unexpected error while running command.
   647  Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'dpkg-query', '--list']
   648  Exit code: 2
   649  Reason: -
   650  Stdout: ''
   651  Stderr: dpkg-query: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1913 package 'file':
   652           multiple non-coinstallable package instances present; most probably due to an upgrade from an unofficial dpkg
   653
   654  curtin: Installation failed with exception: Unexpected error while running command.
   655  Command: ['curtin', 'curthooks']
   656  Exit code: 3
   657  Reason: -
   658  Stdout: start: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: curtin command curthooks
   659          Running curtin builtin curthooks
   660          Configuring target system for distro: ubuntu osfamily: debian
   661          start: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/writing-apt-config: configuring apt configuring apt
   662          Transferred {'subiquity': ''} into new format: {'debconf_selections': {'subiquity': ''}}
   663          curthooks handling apt to target /target with config {'debconf_selections': {'subiquity': ''}}
   664          Running command ['unshare', '--help'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   665          Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'lsb_release', '--all'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   666          Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'dpkg', '--print-architecture'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   667          got primary mirror: None
   668          got security mirror: None
   669          Apt Mirror info: {'PRIMARY': 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/', 'SECURITY': 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/', 'MIRROR': 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/'}
   670          Applying debconf selections
   671          Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'debconf-set-selections'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   672          Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'dpkg-query', '--list'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
   673          finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/writing-apt-config: FAIL: configuring apt configuring apt
   674          finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: FAIL: curtin command curthooks
   675          Traceback (most recent call last):
   676            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
   677              ret = args.func(args)
   678            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 1886, in curthooks
   679              builtin_curthooks(cfg, target, state)
   680            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 1692, in builtin_curthooks
   681              do_apt_config(cfg, target)
   682            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 97, in do_apt_config
   683              apt_config.handle_apt(apt_cfg, target)
   684            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/apt_config.py", line 73, in handle_apt
   685              apply_debconf_selections(cfg, target)
   686            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/commands/apt_config.py", line 162, in apply_debconf_selections
   687              pkgs_installed = distro.get_installed_packages(target)
   688            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 453, in get_installed_packages
   689              (out, _) = subp(['dpkg-query', '--list'], target=target, capture=True)
   690            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 275, in subp
   691              return _subp(*args, **kwargs)
   692            File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 139, in _subp
   693              raise ProcessExecutionError(stdout=out, stderr=err,
   694          curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
   695          Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'dpkg-query', '--list']
   696          Exit code: 2
   697          Reason: -
   698          Stdout: ''
   699          Stderr: dpkg-query: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1913 package 'file':
   700                   multiple non-coinstallable package instances present; most probably due to an upgrade from an unofficial dpkg
   701
   702          Unexpected error while running command.
   703          Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'dpkg-query', '--list']
   704          Exit code: 2
   705          Reason: -
   706          Stdout: ''
   707          Stderr: dpkg-query: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1913 package 'file':
   708                   multiple non-coinstallable package instances present; most probably due to an upgrade from an unofficial dpkg
   709
   710
   711  Stderr: ''
```

Comment: Is this a plain install, or have you customized the ISO in some way prior to installation? Also, what hardware is this on, and are you using Ubuntu 22.04 or 22.04.1?

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 -> yes plain ubuntu 22.04 live server with in-house deb packages incorporated into ISO, during the install apt step throwing this error and seen the crashed logs. Creating this as a VM on top of KVM hypervisor. using 22.04. when we install the deb packages manually using apt inside VM, installation goes fine and in the end seeing the warnings : couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied) this line we are getting when we use apt way of install